# How can I keep the feet from clipping through the ground?

Tags: animation, keyframes, motion-capture

I am wondering if anyone knows of a quicker or more efficient way to clean up the feet from mocap animations. After retargeting the mocap data to my armature, the feet on my character will usually clip through the ground plane as seen in the images. To fix this I manually edit the keyframes so that the feet stay above the ground properly. This however can take a while if my character is doing a lot of walking in the animation. Does anyone know of a better way to streamline this process?[image]

[image]